# Can not include files in Windows Forms project

Tags: c++, windows, forms, include

I have created project `Calculator` in Windows forms. Also I have a logic of my calculator in other cpp file `logic.cpp`.

The problem: I can't include files `logic.cpp` and `<msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>` in `Calculator.h`.

Also I can include `logic.cpp` when this file is free from other includes.

Here is code: 
 **Calculator.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "E:\november\CalculatorForm\CalculatorForm\logic.cpp"
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

namespace CalculatorForm {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
...
}
```

**logic.cpp**

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool isMultiplicationOrDevision(char c) {
    if (c == '*' || c == '/')return true;
    return false;
}
bool isSumOrSubtraction(char c) {
    if (c == '+' || c == '-')return true;
    return false;
}
double doOp(char c, double a, double b) {
    switch (c)
    {
    case '*':
        return a*b;
    case '/':
        if (!b) {
            return 0;
        }
        return a / b;
    case '+':
        return a + b;
    case '-':
        return a - b;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
class Expression {
private:
    vector<double> values;
    vector<char> operators;
public:
    Expression(string expr) {
        string t;
        for each  (char c in expr)
        {
            if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '/' || c == '*') {
                values.push_back(stod(t));
                t.clear();
                operators.push_back(c);
            }
            else {
                t += c;
            }

        }
        values.push_back(stod(t));
    }
    Expression(vector<double> values, vector<char> operators) {
        this->values = values;
        this->operators = operators;
    }
    double getResult() {
        auto i = find_if(operators.begin(), operators.end(), isMultiplicationOrDevision);
        while (i != operators.end()) {
            doOperation(i);
            i = find_if(operators.begin(), operators.end(), isMultiplicationOrDevision);
        }
        i = find_if(operators.begin(), operators.end(), isSumOrSubtraction);
        while (i != operators.end()) {
            doOperation(i);
            i = find_if(operators.begin(), operators.end(), isSumOrSubtraction);
        }
        return values[0];
    }
private:
    void doOperation(vector<char>::iterator i) {
        int index = distance(operators.begin(), i);
        double t = doOp(operators[index], values[index], values[index + 1]);
        operators.erase(i);
        values.erase(values.begin() + index);
        values[index] = t;
    }

};
string checkForBrackets(string s) {
    for (auto i = s.begin(); i < s.end(); i++) {
        string::iterator start;
        if (*i == '(') {
            int dist = distance(s.begin(), i);
            string t(i, s.end());
            t.erase(t.begin());
            string temp(s.begin(), i);
            s = temp + checkForBrackets(t);
            i = s.begin();
            advance(i, dist);
        }
        if (*i == ')') {
            i = s.erase(i);
            string t(s.begin(), i);
            Expression e(t);
            double res = e.getResult();
            s.erase(s.begin(), i);
            s = to_string(res) + s;
            return s;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
string doCalculating(string t) {
    t = checkForBrackets(t);
    Expression a(t);
    t = to_string(a.getResult());
    return t;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't include `*.cpp` files.

Comment: As @MikeCAT said you should'n include .cpp files. You should create a header file(.h) which contains definitions of functions in your .cpp file and include this header file in other files.

Answer (score 0):

include the .h files in your .cpp files and add an include guard to prevent the variables and functions from being redeclared